# Cocoa - Adding menu to support versions? (Like in TextEdit)

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument, autosave

In TextEdit, if you click the little dropdown next to the filename you get a menu which shows a couple of entries including `Rename`, `Move to iCloud`, `Move To`, `Duplicate`, `Lock` and finally `Browse All Versions`.

[image: TextEdit]

I'm wondering how to support this menu? On my app I have the disclosure indictor, but get no menu which I click it. Do I need to add this menu via code? If so, i'm assuming I need to link it to the window somehow, but I don't see a proper place to do so. Any suggestions on what i'm missing?

[image: SQL]

Comment: Did you put the disclosure triangle there?  I like your Toolbar Icons BTW!

Comment: @trojanfoe I did not add the disclosure triangle. I was working on adding version support and the disclosure triangle appeared once I returned true for both `preservesVersions` and `autosavesInPlace` for my NSDocument object. Thanks for the comment on the icons, i'll pass it onto the designer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I was overriding:

`- (void)menuNeedsUpdate:(NSMenu *)menu`

I didn't need to be overriding this method, so I removed it. As soon as I did that, my menu started working.

Answer (score 3):

You get this functionality "for free" when using NSDocument subclasses in document-based applications. As long as you've implemented everything outlined here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html

... versioning should "automagically" work as it's directly affected by implementing auto-save.

Things to consider:

1. What's the minimum OS version you're targeting?
2. Are you customizing anything to do with the Window's title bar?
3. Does your NSDocument subclass implement modern (non-deprecated) read/write methods or are you doing something "old or funky"?

Comment: 1. I'm ok supporting 10.7+
2. I am not doing any customization to the title bar.
3. I believe the methods I'm subclassing as modern: `- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError` and `- (BOOL)readFromFileWrapper:(NSFileWrapper *)fileWrapper ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError`.

I've gone through that document and I'm fairly certain that I have added support for everything. I think at this point, I'm going to attempt creating a basic text editing app and see if I can get versions working.

Comment: Looking at your answer above, I'd say "messing with the title bar's menu" counts as "customizing anything to do with the window's title bar." :-) Glad you found it. Please mark your answer as accepted to close the question.