# Programmatically Show Versions Popup Menu for Document-Based App

Tags: cocoa, titlebar, versions, popupmenu, document-based

We have a custom window and titlebar for a document-based app, and we would like to support versioning with the standard disclosure button that appears beside the document title. Here is an image of the disclosure button and the popup menu when it is clicked (from TextEdit):

[image: Grab of TextEdit versions disclosure button and popup menu]

Is there a way to programmatically show this versions popup menu for a custom disclosure button?

A related question appears here, but with different criteria:

[Cocoa - Adding menu to support versions? (Like in TextEdit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821282/cocoa-adding-menu-to-support-versions-like-in-textedit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't show programmatically the *system* version menu, but you can create your own and call the NSDocument methods

```
- (void)lockDocument:(id)sender
- (void)duplicateDocument:(id)sender
- revertToContentsOfURL:ofType:error:
- (void)browseDocumentVersions:(id)sender
```

lockDocument and browseDocumentVersions require 10.8

Comment: Great answer. This looks like the route to go.